# How to make these imgs 2 rows, overflow the browser be seen with scroll right? not change to row 3

Tags: html, css

How to make these imgs 2 rows, overflow the browser be seen with scroll right? not change to row 3.

http://jsfiddle.net/GW3rU/

```
    <div class="wp">
        <img src="http://guitarcleaning.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/black_fender_stratocaster.jpg">
        <img src="http://guitarcleaning.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/black_fender_stratocaster.jpg">
        <img src="http://guitarcleaning.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/black_fender_stratocaster.jpg">
        <img src="http://guitarcleaning.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/black_fender_stratocaster.jpg">
        <img src="http://guitarcleaning.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/black_fender_stratocaster.jpg">
        <img src="http://guitarcleaning.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/black_fender_stratocaster.jpg">
        <img src="http://guitarcleaning.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/black_fender_stratocaster.jpg">
        <img src="http://guitarcleaning.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/black_fender_stratocaster.jpg">
        <img src="http://guitarcleaning.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/black_fender_stratocaster.jpg">
        <img src="http://guitarcleaning.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/black_fender_stratocaster.jpg">
        <img src="http://guitarcleaning.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/black_fender_stratocaster.jpg">
        <img src="http://guitarcleaning.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/black_fender_stratocaster.jpg">
        <img src="http://guitarcleaning.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/black_fender_stratocaster.jpg">
        <img src="http://guitarcleaning.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/black_fender_stratocaster.jpg">
    </div>
```

​

CSS

```
.wp img{
    width:170px;
    height:170px;
}
.wp{
    height: 340px;/*make 2 row?*/
    width: 855px;/*5 column*/

    /*center horizontal*/
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

​

Comment: is this what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/fWMhJ/

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to scorll in browser scroll bar not just in the wrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include `overflow-x: scroll`:

```
.wp{
    height: 340px;/*make 2 row?*/
    width: 855px;/*5 column*/

    /*center horizontal*/
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

**EDIT**

Okay, now I get what you want. Your code was ok before. You're trying to put 14 images in 2 rows of 5 images each. Is that right?

You should either reduce your number of images to 10, increase the size of your `.wp` div to 7 images, or manually break the line at the middle of the list. The document will scroll, but the div won't.

Comment: Thanks for reply, if I set overflow: hidden, then I can't scroll right to see the img overflow the browser.

Comment: Sorry, then you should set overflow: scroll, or simply overflow-x: scroll for just the horizontal bar.

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the overflow on the container to scroll on the x.

```
.wp{
height: 340px;/*make 2 row?*/
width: 855px;/*5 column*/

/*center horizontal*/
position: absolute;
margin-top: auto;
margin-bottom: auto;
top:0;
bottom: 0;
overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/GW3rU/1/

Comment: Of course it does, you have your width set at 855px you need it set around 1300px to take 7 images wide.